# Upgrade notification urge me to "upgrade" a module to the currently using version

Tags: updating

The below image is in Chinese so you might not understand. But in this screen, Drupal urge me to install [PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) (PHP filter) version 8.x-1.1 while showing the currently installed version **already** is 8.x-1.1.

This is a bit annoying. I've already rebuilt cache a few times but the issue persist. How do I fix this?

[image: Drupal update manager screen]

Comment: If anything, in the contrary, it should urge you to uninstall the module. As the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) mentions `Enabling this module can cause security and performance issues as it allows users to execute PHP code on your site. There are better alternatives out there that do not expose such vulnerabilities on your site.`

Comment: @NoSssweat: There are practical reasons for the site to use this module. Also, this is not what the message tells me.